# Model decay in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas data frame:

| user | day | value | value_cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| Allen | 2021-02-01 | 2 | 3 |
| Allen | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 6 |
| Allen | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 10 |
| Karen | 2021-01-01 | 5 | 5 |
| Karen | 2021-02-01 | 6 | 11 |
| Karen | 2021-03-01 | 7 | 18 |
| Karen | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 26 |

Based on the above, I would like to add two columns that calculate decay in two different ways.

## Version 1

This one is fairly straight forward. I simply want to take the current value plus the past values multiplied by the decay factor of 0.1.

| user | day | value | value_cumulative | decay_v1 | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1.000 | `= 1` |
| Allen | 2021-02-01 | 2 | 3 | 2.100 | `= 2 + 0.1 * 1` |
| Allen | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 6 | 3.210 | `= 3 + 0.1 * 2.1` |
| Allen | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 10 | 4.321 | `= 4 + 0.1 * 3.21` |
| Karen | 2021-01-01 | 5 | 5 | 5.000 | `= 5` |
| Karen | 2021-02-01 | 6 | 11 | 6.500 | `= 6 + 0.1 * 5` |
| Karen | 2021-03-01 | 7 | 18 | 7.650 | `= 7 + 0.1 * 6.5` |
| Karen | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 26 | 8.765 | `= 8 + 0.1 * 7.65` |

## Version 2

This one is a bit more complicated. I'm using the following formula:

```
decay_v2 = 1 - exp(-x*value_cumulative)
```

where x is defined as follows:

```
x = -log(1-sat)/center
```

where I have chosen `sat = 0.05` and center as the value_cumulative from `2021-03-01`.
In the formula column below, the x is therefore:

```
 Allen: -log(1-0.05)/6  = 0.0085489

 Karen: -log(1-0.05)/18 = 0.0028496
```

| user | day | value | value_cumulative | decay_v2 | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 0.009 | `= 1-exp(-x*1)` |
| Allen | 2021-02-01 | 2 | 3 | 0.025 | `= 1-exp(-x*3)` |
| Allen | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 6 | 0.050 | `= 1-exp(-x*6)` |
| Allen | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 10 | 0.082 | `= 1-exp(-x*10)` |
| Karen | 2021-01-01 | 5 | 5 | 0.014 | `= 1-exp(-x*5)` |
| Karen | 2021-02-01 | 6 | 11 | 0.031 | `= 1-exp(-x*11)` |
| Karen | 2021-03-01 | 7 | 18 | 0.050 | `= 1-exp(-x*18)` |
| Karen | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 26 | 0.071 | `= 1-exp(-x*26 )` |

I have the feeling that it must be possible to somehow implement this using the ewm function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) but am unable to get it to work. Any ideas on how this could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this with a function that implements a simple loop of the following type for decay_v1:

```
  decay_v1 = value.copy()
  
  # Replace all values except the first one, which is our starting point.
  for i in range(1, len(value)):
    decay_v1[i] = value[i] + 0.1 * decay_v1[i-1]
```

I applied this for all user names separately and then appended the results back together. For decay_v2 I solved it in a similar way.